# Plot legend obscures plot lines in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm using this code found in [matplotlib's gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-errorbar-limits-simple-py):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(10)
y = 2.5 * np.sin(x / 20 * np.pi)
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)

plt.errorbar(x, y + 3, yerr=yerr, label='both limits (default)')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, label='uplims=True')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 1, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, lolims=True,
             label='uplims=True, lolims=True')

upperlimits = [True, False] * 5
lowerlimits = [False, True] * 5
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, uplims=upperlimits, lolims=lowerlimits,
             label='subsets of uplims and lolims')

plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

and, I receive the following output in the terminal in jupyter:

[image]

However, in the matplotlib gallery, the legend is tucked in nicely below the errorbar limit selection:

[image]

How would I sort this out? I'm having the same issue with a few other plots at the moment with my project, with the legent obstructing the plot, and I've made no progress so far.

Comment: Also see [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) or simply change the figure size `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example simply adding `plt.tight_layout()` in the end seems to fix the overlap.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(10)
y = 2.5 * np.sin(x / 20 * np.pi)
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)

plt.errorbar(x, y + 3, yerr=yerr, label='both limits (default)')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, label='uplims=True')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 1, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, lolims=True,
             label='uplims=True, lolims=True')

upperlimits = [True, False] * 5
lowerlimits = [False, True] * 5
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, uplims=upperlimits, lolims=lowerlimits,
             label='subsets of uplims and lolims')


plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.tight_layout() # <- add this
```

However, to maintain consistency you can adjust the size of the figure to avoid overlapping legends.

For this example it would be:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5)) # <- add a figsize
x = np.arange(10)
y = 2.5 * np.sin(x / 20 * np.pi)
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)

plt.errorbar(x, y + 3, yerr=yerr, label='both limits (default)')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 2, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, label='uplims=True')

plt.errorbar(x, y + 1, yerr=yerr, uplims=True, lolims=True,
             label='uplims=True, lolims=True')

upperlimits = [True, False] * 5
lowerlimits = [False, True] * 5
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, uplims=upperlimits, lolims=lowerlimits,
             label='subsets of uplims and lolims')


plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```